# Implementing Coinbase API in Wordpress to display exchange rates

Tags: wordpress, api, bitcoin, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I am trying to use the Coinbase API to pull live bitcoin data to my Wordpress site and display the exchange rate. I want to achieve something similar to this: http://preev.com/

There are a few things I would really appreciate help with:
 1. How to extract bitcoin rate against other currencies from the Coinbase API?
 2. What do I need to replace in my wordpress theme file to display the information on the page?

I am new to using API's and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally what I would do is get a wordpress plugin that allows you to make PHP widgets.

Then simply put the appropriate PHP and CSS code, to display your data.

Here are some good php widget plugins.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-text-widget/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/